# The type or namespace name of solution could not be found

Tags: presentation

I have a fresh installation of Sitecore 8.2 MVC 4.6.1. There is a custom item called *Home* and it has a layout. When previewing this item, it gives this compilation error.

Why is it reading from a temp file. How can i fix this.

[image]

**Default.cshtml**

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Extensions
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
@model RenderingModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <div class="container">        
            @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("page-content")
        </div>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Sitecore cannot resolve a custom namespace (it maybe be used on layout or rendering view)

First, make sure that dll with **Trallcore** type (is it a type?) is present in your bin folder.

Next

Please check whether your `Views` folder (folder where a view where this particular view with **Tralcore** (`using Tralcore`) reference is used) contains the `web.config`  with missing namespace.

or

If you are not using your own `web.config`, please make sure you provide a full namespace to the **Trallcore** type (is it a type?)

**For example.**

Assuming you are using type `Item`.

`using Item` might not be enough (if there is no namespace in a `web.config`)

and you have to write something like this (in your View's code)

`using Sitecore.Data.Item`

Comment: Not using any custom web.config. The web.config inside the views folder references `Trialcore` namespace. The `Trialcore.dll` is present in the bin folder. Also, in the cshtml, there is no `using Trialcore` statement, but it is somehow appearing in the temp file.

Comment: are you able to resolve this issue after deleting files & folders inside temp folder ? please confirm.

Comment: I deleted all the files under \root\...but the issue remains..:(

Answer (score 0):

This seems strange but worked for me.

Copy the `Trialcore.dll` from VS Solution's bin folder to the instance's bin folder.

I'm still surprised as I never had to do this for previous projects.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do you deploy from VS to the instance?  I would also check that **Copy Local** is set to *true* for that DLL Reference.

Comment: In the VS Solution,the `Trialcore.dll` is inside the bin folder and hidden by default. This does not have the `Copy Local` property.

Comment: If your solution needs to have that DLL in your bin directory, then I *would* add a reference to it in your VS solution and make sure it is *not* hidden.